# How do I use a conditional in nmake

Tags: nmake

I want to be able to compile both an EXE and a separate DLL from C source code. I also want to define different C flags for the C processor to distinguish between the two. The following nmake lines only yields errors.

I am able to pass in a macro as a workaround and throwing extra macro definitions in the rules works also. I'd still like to accomplish the same merely based on the target macro and conditionals so that I can follow the Makefile logic more easily.

```
CC = cl
!IF $(@) == "test"
CFLAGS = /MD /DWIN /DDLL
!ELSE
CFLAGS = /MD /DWIN
!ENDIF
```

Here's the complaint from *NMAKE*

```
PS C:\Users\dholstei\projects\VHF\src-dll> nmake -f .\Makefile.mak test

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26729.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

.\Makefile.mak(10) : warning U4006: special macro undefined : '$(@)'
.\Makefile.mak(11) : fatal error U1023: syntax error in expression
Stop.
```

Comment: The `!IF` is used when the makefile is _parsed_, while the `$@` only has meaning when the makefile run after being parsed.